# Some females don't have the right skeleton

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I'm using [XPMSE](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/68000) but some female are not using it properly(Mostly guards). and when I change their gender with console commands their arms work fine but of course the body is male.
[image]

This is normal female form
[image]

This is when I change the gender
[image]

I've tried using [XPMS](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/26800), FNIS, Arm fix patch and Nemesis. Nothing works. And if it matters I'm also using UNP.

My load order

```
Skyrim.esm
Update.esm
Dawnguard.esm
HearthFires.esm
Dragonborn.esm
HighResTexturePack01.esp
HighResTexturePack02.esp
HighResTexturePack03.esp
FNIS.esp
XPMSE.esp
SkyUI.esp
Reliquary of Myth.esp
Inigo.esp
Run For Your Lives.esp
Arcanum.esp
Immersive Music Temples.esp
Immersive Music.esp
Apocalypse - The Spell Package.esp
Auto Unequip Ammo.esp
RoM - Apocalypse Patch.esp
RoM - Dragon Priest Masks Pack.esp
DragonbornAscendant.esp
RaceMenu.esp
RaceMenuPlugin.esp
DSerCombatGameplayOverhaul.esp
```

Comment: Please carefully read the question before casting your close vote on this question for being a technical support question **for Minecraft**.

Comment: Did you sort your mods with LOOT?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what's happening. Some female npcs animations, have the male flag(and it's normal). To fix this you can use a Synthesis or Bashed patch.